# Trouble using User Input and FileInputStream to create a file and read Integers from that file

Tags: java

I cannot explain my problem very well, this is the prompt.

I believe I am going in the right direction, my professor really went through this fast. Even though I am using the book and asking for help, it is to no avail.

```
 '**Ask the user to enter a filename on the keyboard, including “.txt.”  Read five integers from that file (all on the same line, separated by spaces) and tell the user their sum by printing it to the screen (console).**'
```

It compiles and runs, but when entering the filename(io.txt) I get **an Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found**

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String myString = " ";
    Scanner inputStream = null;


    System.out.println("Please enter a Filename, including '.txt' at the end: ");
    myString = in.next();

    try
    {

       inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(myString));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) //Giving the file not found a name, 
    {
                System.out.println("Invalid File or filename");
                System.out.println("Or could not be found,try again");
                System.exit(0);
    }
                //True will always add on, not overwrite

    int n1 = inputStream.nextInt();
    int n2 = inputStream.nextInt();
    int n3 = inputStream.nextInt();
    int n4 = inputStream.nextInt();
    int n5 = inputStream.nextInt();

    String line =  inputStream.nextLine(); //wait for new line, get the next line
    inputStream.close( );
    System.out.println("The five numbers read from the file are: ");
    System.out.println(n1+" , "+ n2 + ", "+ n3 + ", "+ n4 +", "+ n5);
    System.out.println("Which adds together to eqaul: " + (n1+n2+n3+n4+n5));


}
```

I want direction, not for someone to solve it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing the code you gave it returns with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at com.example.Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

which is the following line in your code

```
String line = inputStream.nextLine(); //wait for new line, get the next line
```

So your code tries to read another line from the file, but it can't find one. In reality what this means is your code is expecting to read
`"1 2 3 4 5\n"` from a file `io.txt` whereas the file actually contains `"1 2 3 4 5"` (no newline at the end of the file).

However since you've already read all the integers you needed you can simply stop there.

Also make sure to close your file stream.

Comment: Ahh I see where I went wrong, it helped me understand more, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use in. nextLine()  in place of in. next().